# IOError in Boto3 download_file

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

**Background**

I am using the following Boto3 code to download file from S3.

```
for record in event['Records']:
    bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = record['s3']['object']['key']
    print (key)
    if key.find('/') < 0 :
    if len(key) > 4 and key[-5:].lower() == '.json': //File is uploaded outside any folder

        download_path = '/tmp/{}{}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), key)
    else:
        download_path = '/tmp/{}/{}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), key)//File is uploaded inside a folder
```

If a new file is uploaded in S3 bucket, this code is triggered and that newly uploaded file is downloaded by this code.

This code works fine when uploaded outside any folder.

However, when I upload a file inside a directory, IO error happens.
Here is a dump of the IO error I am encountering.

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> **/tmp/316bbe85-fa21-463b-b965-9c12b0327f5d/test1/customer1.json.586ea9b8**:
> IOError

`test1` is the directory inside my S3 bucket where `customer1.json` is uploaded.

**Query**

Any thoughts on how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Error raised because you attempted to download and save file into directory which not exists. Use [os.mkdir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.mkdir) prior downloading file to create an directory.

```
# ...
else:
    item_uuid = str(uuid.uuid4())
    os.mkdir('/tmp/{}'.format(item_uuid))
    download_path = '/tmp/{}/{}'.format(item_uuid, key)  # File is uploaded inside a folder
```

**Note**: It's better to use [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) while operating with systems paths. So code above could be rewritten to:

```
# ...
else:
    item_uuid = str(uuid.uuid4())
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(['tmp', item_uuid]))
    download_path = os.path.join(['tmp', item_uuid, key]))
```

Also error may be raises because you including '/tmp/' in download path for s3 bucket file, do not include `tmp` folder as likely it's not exists on s3. Ensure you are on the right way by using that articles:

- [Amazon S3 upload and download using Python/Django](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/upload-and-download-files-tofrom-amazon-s3-using-pythondjango/)
- [Python s3 examples](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/jewel/radosgw/s3/python/#python-s3-examples)

Comment: ok,but even after trying this out same error persists.[Errno 2] No such file or directory: /tmp/316bbe85-fa21-463b-b965-9c12b0327f5d/test1/customer1.json.586ea9b8: IOError...............................................I print my download_path,it gives  "/tmp/316bbe85-fa21-463b-b965-9c12b0327f5d" and key gives as "test1/customer1.json" ,however in the error i see an extra ".586ea9b8" appended...Is this causing the error now...and if it is ,how can we eliminate this.

Comment: i guess its right,but in my scenario,folder is getting created successfully,however when the s3.download_file is called,it throws error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: /tmp/316bbe85-fa21-463b-b965-9c12b0327f5d/test1/customer1.js‌​on.586ea9b8.

Comment: Likely because you provided wrong params to download_file, checkout links i've provided and you would definetely find way to get files from s3 without errors.

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko I am facing the same issue. The link you have provided are old. Can you help me in solving the issue? I am using flask+apache as a backend server and I am downloading a s3 file to ec2 machine using s3_client.download_file() method.

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko I solved it by changing the owner of flask and it's sub-directories to "www-data". For now it is working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Had the same error with appended string:  No such file or directory: '<my_path>/<my_file>.tar.DAe7E798' Turns out the problem is with the destination file ie download_path. In my case I had an Amazon EBS directory that gave an error but when I tried to download to Amazon EFS it worked. Another crazy thing was that AWS cli cp command "aws s3 cp" worked with EBS. Seems it is a boto3 thing

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue, and the error message caused a lot of confusion, (the random string extension after the file name). In my case it was caused by the missing directory path, which didn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for helping Andriy Ivaneyko,I found an solution using boto3.

Using this following code i am able to accomplish my task.

```
for record in event['Records']:
    bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = record['s3']['object']['key']
    fn='/tmp/xyz'
    fp=open(fn,'w')
    response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=key)
    contents = response['Body'].read()
    fp.write(contents)
    fp.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that download_path is wrong. Whenever you are trying to download any file which is under a directory in your s3 bucket, the download path becomes something like:

```
download_path = /tmp/<uuid><object key name>
where <object key name>  = "<directory name>/<object name>"
```

This makes the download path as:

```
download_path = /tmp/<uuid><directory name>/<object key name>
```

The code will fail because there is no directory exist with uuid-directory name. Your code only allows download of a file under /tmp directory only.

To fix the issue, considering splitting your key while making the download path and you can as well avoid check where the file was uploaded in the bucket. This will just take object file name only in the download path. For example:

```
for record in event['Records']:
    bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = record['s3']['object']['key']
    print (key) 
    download_path = '/tmp/{}{}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), key.split('/')[-1])
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the answer I was trying to find all along!