# File path modified with code after pushing changes to Python/Flask app with Heroku CLI causing FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, amazon-s3, flask, heroku-cli

I'm having difficulty troubleshooting this issue and would appreciate any suggestions or ideas.  I've searched quite a bit online with no luck, but I'm also a newbie so the solution could be really obvious.

I have a Flask app running a Python API that generates some pickle files.  The app is hosted on Heroku. The files are stored on AWS-S3. When the app creates files on Heroku, they will have a path like this:
`mydirectory/myfilename.pkl`

But when I push changes to my app using the Heroku CLI and then run a function which accesses the same file at `mydirectory/myfilename.pkl`, I get this error:

> FileNotFound[Errno 2] No such file or directory: "mydirectory/myfilename.pkl.ceDd4963"

It looks like some type of caching or versioning, but I have no idea how this string at the end of the path is being generated.  It is a different string with each request.  I do not have this issue when pushing changes locally, it is only on Heroku.  I no longer get an error if I create a new file after I've pushed changes, but this is not a working solution.

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas of what is causing this and how I can disable it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A colleague forwarded this link to me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39569718/io-error-in-boto3-download-file

It looks like this is the same issue I have and using the os.mkdir error handling fixed my issue :)